# Command for Idle timout

Tags: timeout

`timeout` is nice for killing a command that does not complete within n seconds.

Is there a similar command to kill a command that has not printed anything on stdout for n seconds (and which therefore is probably stuck)?

Edit:

```
socat -T120 'exec:python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py' -
```

works nice, except it does not set $? if the job is killed. Is there a way I can make `socat` do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to terminate a python script if it doesn’t output anything to the terminal in 2 min](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/626909)